# router.push query getting overwritten by url param

Tags: next.js

So when I use Router.push the query I am sending with it is getting overwritten

```
Router.push({
 pathname: `/product/${subCategoryValue}`,
 query: { category: helpWith, industry: industry },
});
```

When I `console.log(query)` on the `/product/${subCategoryValue}` page the only thing that shows up is the url param (subCategoryValue).

Comment: `subCategoryValue` is not a query param right? e.g: `?categoryId=1`

Comment: but when i console.log(query) it is appears there

Comment: Can you show us the code for the `/product/${subCategoryValue}` page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it using this code:

```
Router.push(
 {
  pathname: `/product/${subCategoryValue},
  query: { category: helpWith, industry: industryValue }
 },
 `/product/${subCategoryValue}`
);
```